# How can I add a MouseListener to every element (except one) inside an EditorPart?

Tags: java, swt

When the user clicks somewhere outside a a Text widget, I want to deactivate its scrollbars.

It works like this:

```
public class RttProjectActionEditor extends EditorPart {
    ...
    MouseListener exitCommandText = new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.widget != textArea) {
                textArea.getVerticalBar().setEnabled(false);
            } 
        }
    };

    labelGroup.addMouseListener(exitCommandText);
    myComposite.addMouseListener(exitCommandText);
    ... // all widgets in my EditorPart
```

But this way I have to add them one by one to all widgets that this EditorPart is the owner of. Is there a better and simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively add listeners to a control and any children (if it is a composite) using something like this:

```
private void hookRecursively(Control c, MouseListener listener) {
    c.addMouseListener(listener);

    if (c instanceof Composite) {
        Control[] children = ((Composite) c).getChildren();
        for (Control element : children) {
            hookRecursively(element, listener);
        }
    }
}
```